# spring3 ibatis2.x multiple datasource

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, datasource, ibatis

I use spring ibatis to connection Oracle multiple user space.

It is seems like User A,User B,User System.

The User System is always to used. the other user while opration in a Task(Thread)

spring.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="System" />
    <property name="password" value="system" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="A" />
    <property name="password" value="a" />
</bean>

    <bean id="dataSource3" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="B" />
    <property name="password" value="b" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlMapClient1" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlMapClient2" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3" />
</bean>
```

In Dao:

```
public class BaseDao extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport {
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());  

@Resource(name = "sqlMapClient")
private SqlMapClient sqlMapClient;


@PostConstruct
public void initSqlMapClient() {
    super.setSqlMapClient(sqlMapClient);
}
  }

  public class UserDao extends BaseDao {
       public void test()
       {
           this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("....");
       }
  }
```

**Task: in taskJob i want to opration other datasorce. how to implement it?**

```
public class TaskJob {

          //@Autowired
          //UserDao userDao;
           public void test(){
                 //to get other sqlmapclient in UserDao
                userDao.test();//for User A,User B,User ....
           }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using SqlMapClientDaoSupport. If you are ok not to use SqlMapClientDaoSupport then the following solution should suffice.

MapClientFactoryBean should not have the data source

```
<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml" />
 </bean>
```

Have two UserDAO(One for Each datasource)

```
<bean id = "userDAO" class = "com.xxxx.UserDAO">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="sqlMapClient" ref = "sqlMapClient">
<bean id = "userDAO1" class = "com.xxxx.UserDAO">
     <property name="dataSource2" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="sqlMapClient" ref = "sqlMapClient">
</bean>
```

Refer here for more details http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/msg04432.html

Couldnt test the code myself. Please try.

Comment: Thanks,but This solution is too much trouble.Have a more simple way?Oracle users a lot.I need to cycle the these users in the thread

Comment: SqlMapClientDaoSupport  is designed to support only one SqlMapClient .. So I really doubt if you can do anything with the existing code ..

Comment: Can I create DataSource by myself not use spring(aop),like:for(DataSource dt...)(new UserDao().set(dt);)